# How can I reference from nested lambda to upper lambda implicit name of a single parameter (it)?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

For example, I have a this piece of code:

```kotlin
                testie.testy?.let { // reference to this it
                    testContext.update {
                        it.testiest = it //How can I there reference to upper-level it?
                    }
                }
```

How can I reference from `it.tesiest` to `it` in the `let` block?

For workaround now, I using the named parameter in the upper lambda. But I think that there other ways to reference in the right place without the introduction of the named variable.

Comment: You need to define a name for at least one parameter. In geneal with nested lamdas is much clearer to do that (even if you don't need to refer to the outer one)

Comment: @al3c I understand that. But I can reference in a lambda to `this` using `@` that very convenient